# extract interface that a class implementing using AST parser

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt, abstract-syntax-tree

I am compiling a project source using AST parser. In what way i can extract class hierarchy infromation, that is whether it is implementing any interface or extends from another class?

Comment: Unless all you want is the syntax of the signatures ( or a mere list of class names extended) in a class in a specific file  you've  parsed, you're going to need full name and type resolution across many files (some source files, some class files) for Java.  That's much more than you have with just an AST.

Comment: Vote or accept an answer, if it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can visit the `TypeDeclaration` node and get the type binding from it.

```
ITypeBinding typeBind = typDec.resolveBinding();
```

You can then get the super class and implemented interfaces as follows:

```
public boolean visit(TypeDeclaration typeDeclaration) {

        ITypeBinding typeBind = typeDeclaration.resolveBinding();
        ITypeBinding superTypeBind = typeBind.getSuperclass();
        ITypeBinding[] interfaceBinds = typeBind.getInterfaces();      

        return true;
}
```

Comment: i am not using IType instance

Comment: This does not employ IType. UseS the AST Visitor pattern and TypeDeclaration AST node. Updating the answer for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an IType instance (type), you can get get the class hierarchy in an ITypeHierarchy as follows

```
ITypeHierarchy typeHierarchie = type.newTypeHierarchy(new NullProgressMonitor());
```

The ITypeHierarchy has methods to query the implemented interfaces

```
typeHierarchie.getSuperInterfaces(type);
```

as well as which classes were extended

```
typeHierarchie.getSuperclass(type); 
typeHierarchie.getAllSuperclasses(type);
```