# How to check if a field's implements an interface?

Tags: eclipse-jdt, lombok

If I have an `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.FieldDeclaration`, how would I check if the type of the field implements an interface, let's say `Serializable`? I don't see any documentation for `org.eclipse.jdt.internal`.

I found [extract interface that a class implementing using AST parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800942/extract-interface-that-a-class-implementing-using-ast-parser), but that one talks about `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.FieldDeclaration`.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** At first I didn't look at the package and thought you were asking about `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.FieldDeclaration`. That's what the answer is good for.

If you need to work with **internal** classes, we expect that you *know exactly* what you are doing. There won't be any documentation for those (but conceptually the same approach as shown for the public API can similarly be used for the internal AST and bindings, too).

---

Type compatibility is best tested using the corresponding bindings, so your quest would consist of theses steps:

1. From the `FieldDeclaration` obtain the binding using `resolveBinding()`
2. From the field binding retrieve the type binding
3. Once get a binding representing the expected super type `Serializable`
4. Ask the actual field type `isSubTypeCompatible(serializableType)`

You'll find some more details - in particular on (3) - in a [recent discussion in the JDT forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1084603/).

Comment: Ah, I see. Instead of the methods, I access the public fields directly. I see `isSubtypeOf` which seems like the replacement for `isSubTypeCompatible`, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's for strict subtype compatible, and it seems you indeed don't need the subtleties of assignment compatibility a la `isCompatibleWith`.

Comment: Having trouble with step 3. I don't see any equivalents to the internal API. `ASTParser.createBindings` and it doesn't look like it'll work with what I have. Same for the example of `IJavaProject.findType("java.lang.RuntimeException")`, which looks for the class relative to a project. BTW, the FAQ page won't load for me.

Comment: OK, one last hint on internal classes: internally the compiler has no notion of a project, that's an IDE concept. Internally we use org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment. In this case I should warn you even more: it's internal so it can change without notice and for Java 9 LookupEnvironment *will* change significantly. BTW, what FAQ?

Comment: The FAQ is the link in your reply on the JDT forum. It does load now, but wasn't relevant. Will look into your hint.

Comment: The `FieldBinding` I get from my `FieldDeclaration` is always `null`. I see that I can get the `TypeReference` where I have `checkCastTypesCompatibility` and `checkUnsafeCast`. Maybe I can go from here? Is there a way I could just get a list of all implemented interfaces for the type?

Comment: If you have a `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.FieldDeclaration` with null `binding`, then you are probably not in a situation where reasoning about types is supported. As we don't know how you obtained an instance of this internal class, you're probably left to your own understanding and inventiveness. That's what "internal" means: use at your own risk. Good luck. :)

Comment: I'm realizing now that that's probably what the Lombok developers were talking about when they said that "Lombok can't do resolution" (or it's very difficult to do so). Thanks anyway for the help!